# Sencha Touch 2 Development on a Linux Server

Tags: django, web-applications, sencha-touch-2

**Main Question:** Is it possible to do all development for a Sencha Touch 2 web app on a Linux server?

I have a Linux server already hosting/running a decent size Django web application for the company I work for and want to build a web app for use on iPads in the field (the web app would only have a small amount of functionality for field crews). Ideally, I would be able to do all the development for this web app on the linux server, and not on my personal Windows computer.

I can't find anything that shows how one would set up such a scenario. Do I put the SDK files in my Django project directory? Would they go in an app directory within my Django directory? How do I set up the apache server to manage the Sencha Touch app?

The Sencha "[Getting Started](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/getting_started)" guide shows code for what looks like a Linux type shell (they say to change to the ST directory by doing `cd ~/webroot/sencha-touch-2.0.00gpl/` <- that looks like Linux command line, no?)

Anyone have any guides, information, tutorials, tips about thi

Comment: dude sencha touch is a JS library, why would you that have anything to do with linux ?

Comment: @SreenathSoman I'm not quite sure what you're saying since I think you missed a word or two. I understand that ST is Java, that's not my question. I'm looking for info on where the ST files should exist within my Django project (which is running on a Linux server). All the ST documentation states that you should have a webserver running locally for development. I'm saying, I don't want to do it locally, I want to do it on my already-running web server - which is Linux.

Comment: oh typo, sorry :D. ST is not java its javascript. you can put it anywhere inside your app structure. For eg: put it inside you app folder like /app/sencha-touch/, so that you can use it like this: `<script src="sencha-touch/whatever.js"></script>` in your app

Comment: Alright, see that's what I couldn't find. I had a hunch this was the case, but wasn't sure. I'll go try this out and see how I fair. Thanks o/